# Printing each character of char array instead of each partial one

Tags: c++, pointers, char, printf

Recently I found an interesting question in my exam: **what would be printed by the following code**. I wondered why this code didn't print sequentially *each character of the char array* (i.e "dcba") but *each partial one* (i.e "dcdbcdabcd"), in the reverse order.

By the way, I also want to know which topic is related to this problem.

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char mess[] = "abcd";
    char* ptr;
    ptr = mess + strlen(mess);
    while (ptr > mess)
        printf("%s", --ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the c++ header `#include <iostream>` but add `#include <stdio.h>` for pritnf.  Remove the c++ tag.

Comment: There's still a c-string printed at each iteration, not a single character.

Comment: @babon I think that was the "trick" part of this 'C' question! (This is not modern 'c++' code so I hope this wasn't from a C++ exam)

Comment: @babon that won't work without dereferencing the pointer

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char mess[] = "abcd";` means `mess` aka `&mess[0]` is the address of the string `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', \0 }`.  `ptr = mess + strlen(mess);` means `ptr` initially points to the `\0` of `mess`. In the loop `ptr` is decremented, and the subsequent `printf()` will print from where `ptr` points to till it sees `\0` (i.e. tail of `mess`):

```
// initial:
abcd\0
^----- mess aka &mess[0]
     ^ ptr = mess + strlen(mess) = mess + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your formatter in `printf` printing a string each time, not a character. So it print the string start at `ptr` to the end of `mess`.

Comment: Explaining NUL termination might clarify more.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ Noted. Although base on username, I guess the OP is from my country and have the same background education as I am. I can roughly guess his point of view. He just start to learn at the language and already know about NULL terminate but only miss the point of %s.
My answer may not enough for general view though.

Comment: @TheLongNguyen well, your answers here shouldn't be tailored for the OP, but helpful for  anyone who's researching at the SO Q&A repository.